# Cosine Similarity measure applied on images

Tags: image, matlab, similarity, trigonometry

I am trying to work on a project which requires me to find the similarity between two images. Can anyone help me with the matlab code for applying cosine similarity on images or any other useful information on the same. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the MPEG-7 Visual descriptors if you are interested in doing image similarity [Visual descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_descriptors) . I have had good results from combinations of the EHD (Edge histogram descriptor) and CSD (colour structure descriptor) and there are Matlab implementations on the web (though they are easy enough to implement your self from the original publications)

Some example source: [Content Based Image Retrieval in Matlab](http://code.google.com/p/matlab-cbir/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk)